Работа с пробками по АПИ в рамках конкретной улицы
Сделали скрипт, который через АПИ Яндекс подтягивает уровень пробок в Москве и в зависимости от значения (до 6 баллов или выше 6 баллов) - выдает на сайте 1 из 2 роликов. Смогли это сделать только на примере среднего балла по всей Москве. А возможно ли как-то получать показатель уровня (балла) пробок за конкретную улицу Москвы?

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

В JS API нет возможности получить балл пробок для конкретного участка дороги. Данные пробок по дорогам в нашем сервисе мы отдаем только в виде слоя для отображения или в составе оценки времени в пути по маршруту.
Использование недокументированных методов, а также неотображение данных, полученных с помощью API, является нарушением условий использования API Яндекс Карт.
